# Invalid argument received when running chown in a Linux namespace

Tags: linux, mount, kernel, chown, namespaces

After running something like this:

```
unshare -rUm
mkdir opt
mount --bind opt /opt
touch /opt/test
chown 1000:1000 /opt/test
```

I'm receiving this:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/opt/test': Invalid argument
```

I don't understand why or how can I bypass this issue.